# DocumentDB and insert only architecture

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, azure-cosmosdb

We are looking if an insert-only data architecture would be suitable for our project.

The idea is to store the actual versions in an S3 collection(s) and archived (non actual) versions should be placed in a cheaper S1 collection.

For this approach I have the following concerns:

- As transactions are only scoped on partition level, this means that if a have a trigger or stored procedure to archive the old version when a newer one is created, we can't be sure of an ACID transaction, is this a correct assumption? Is there a way to get around this?
- When you create a collection (which is in fact a partition), you can choose between single partitioned collection and multi partitioned collection. But some Microsoft videos tell me that collections are in fact partitions. Am I correct when I assume that when a chose a multi partitioned collection, that is in fact the same as registering multiple single partioned collections? What is the difference between the two? Can I switch between the two modes in production?
- Is there a limition on the amount of DB-users and permissions in DocumentDB?

Answer (score 4):

You cover a lot of ground in your question, so I'll try to respond to most of what you've asked, but others should chime in with their own insight.

Think of "partitioned collections" under the covers as a set of collections where the system automatically decides what data goes in what partition based upon your chosen partition key. The logic for how many partitions/collections are needed is taken out of your hands as are all of the chores of writing your own partitioning code including the very tricky chore of rebalancing as you scale up and down. This logic is designed to allow you to turn the dial on size and throughput while maintaining <10ms p99 latency on reads and <15ms p99 for writes. If you are building a new system today that you expect to expand over time, I highly recommend that you go with partitioned collections.

A minor argument for the traditional S1, S2, S3 collections/partitions is that you can get started with a lower cost. An S1 can be had for as little as $25/month. The current reasonable minimum for partitioned collections is about $600, but I recently heard that Azure is lowering (maybe has already) that to $150 (1/4 what it was before). An S1+S3 would cost you at least $125 so they are roughly the same.

Right now, you cannot switch between the two modes without backing up and restoring so that's an additional argument for starting with a partitioned collection from the git-go. That said, I hear that automatic migration can be achieved if you ask and I suspect it will eventually be self-service.

You are correct that stored procedure isolation (ACID transactions) only work on a single partition. That is true under either the old S# model and the new partitioned collection model so it's not a difference between the two. I recommend that you only use stored procedures for write (create, upsert, delete) as reads are more efficiently done outside of a stored procedure to allow for secondaries to contribute and you typically don't need ACID transactions for reads. We use our tenantID as our partition key and we never have cross-tenant write transactions so it's not a problem for us. Depending upon your choice of partition key it may not be a problem for your either.

The DocumentDB user/permission system is designed to enable direct client connections with an expiring key like OAUTH. As long as you cache the keys in your end clients, I'm told that it scales well, but if you issue a new key on each request, that has been known to bog it down. If that matches your use case, then great. However, it's not ideal for something like multi-tenancy which is probably better implemented in your middle tier.

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed reply. The differences between the two modes are making more sense to me now.

In you reply you said that logic for partitioning in 'partitioned collection' is handled by Azure. Does this mean that I cannot add custom partition resolvers when using the partitioned collection?

If I would partition on TenantId, what would happen if I choose 'partitioned collection' and the tenant data exceeds the 10gb quota?

Comment: That's correct. The old client-side partition resolver stuff is abstracted away and pushed into the DocumentDB service. You essentially just say what field you want to partition on and it takes care of the rest.

If you choose partitioned collection, you have essentially infinite scalability in terms of size and throughput. Whenever your size exceeds the current partitions or your throughput is not what you asked for, DocumentDB will automatically add partitions and rebalance. It's very similar to the stable hash partition resolver that you may be familiar with.

Comment: Is the following assumption correct? If a choose partitioned collection, and I choose the TenantId as partitionkey. Initially, I will have little tenants, so this means the auto scaling capabilities of Azure will only create one partition, as all the data fits in this one partition. In a next stage, my number of tenants are growing, and that one partition will soon reach it's storing/request unit limits.At this moment, Azure will notice this and creates an extra partition, makes two groups of all tenants and puts the data of group one in partition one, and group two in partition two?

Comment: Also, when at a sudden point, the tenant data is too big (> 10 GB), this means that data would be split between 2 partitions, so this means that I cannot execute stored procedures, triggers, etc targeting both collections for this tenant?

Comment: It's hard to know how many partitions it will actually create and you really shouldn't care. It could be as fine grained as a partition for each unique tenent id or it could be as you suggest a single partition. Scalability is a function of partitions but also secondaries and geography, so you are trusting the DocumentDB service to work all that out and meet their SLAs. It works as you say, it will add partitions and move data around (rebalance) as it determines that's needed.

Comment: If you think a single tenant will be too big, then you may want to add something to the end of your tenant id and use that combined thing as your partition key. That said, I don't believe that the 10GB per partition limit is enforced when you choose partitioned collections. You'd have to chat with the DocumentDB PM's to think through that.

Comment: Comments aren't the place for a discussion and additional questions. Please move this to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/), or post new questions.